# CSS sticky z-index works only on TD not the text content

Tags: html, css, html-table, z-index

I've tried all possible searches and this and got nowhere. I have a table with a `thead tr` set to `position: sticky`, however it does not work as desired - the text content of `td` goes over the sticky `th`, the background covers the elements but text goes over, like a sandwich ;'d.

[Demo](https://jamborski-dev.github.io/bookings/)

[Git](https://github.com/jamborski-dev/bookings)

I have tried using negative `z-index`, `translateZ(0)` and nothing seems to work..

Comment: Have you tried using `top: 0;`?

Comment: Your demo behaves as expected here -- the row in the table header section is sticky and I don't see any other rows covering it. I am using Firefox 87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply removed sticky and then I noticed it covered the sidebar. So keeping sticky and changing the z-index of thead to 200 and the aside tag to 300 worked for me. Let me know if I'm missing something.

```
thead {
position: sticky;
z-index: 200;
}

aside {
grid-area: aside;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 2rem;
height: 100%;
color: var(--theme-light);
background: linear-gradient(30deg, var(--theme-dark), var(--theme-dark_darker));
position: relative;
z-index: 300;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transition: width .2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: great! this worked like a charm! though cannot really understand why aside was affecting this at all

Comment: When I removed position sticky, thead became an element with position static. Z-Index does not affect position static elements so it was placed above the sidebar. When you add position sticky it becomes a positioned element and because you don't have a set z-index, it was automatically placed behinds things that had a higher z-index or position static elements. For example the main table which is position static.